# Variable disappearing in SPSS

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, binary-data

I am new to SPSS, so any help is appreciated.

I am performing a binary logistic regression analysis using the categorical variable of ethnicity/race, among other things. There are six examples of race that include test subjects. I have properly recoded them into different variables under the Transition tab. When I include all six of them, they all show up under Box 0 as a variable not included in the equation.  However, the last one, regardless of what it is, does not show up as a variable included in the equation under Box 1.

Basically, I cannot get all six races to show up at the same time...unless I remove the constant.  However, the results are highly highly suspect when I do that.  I need help keeping the constant in and having all six races included in the final analysis under Box 1.

Comment: I suggest adding the tag "spss" to this question.

Comment: Thank you James.  I just did that.

Comment: It is impossible to fit a model with intercept and 6 regression coefficients for race given just 6 unique races in the data. It is not the problem of software or your usage of software. It is problem that the model you wanted does not exist. You can check the collinearity.

Comment: Thank you @user158565.  One additional question to add on.  I am mostly concerned with the sig result in Box 1.  The sig result for Ethnicity (which I assume to be general) changes depending on which one gets "left out".  How do I know what the correct sig result should be?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With categorical variables, it is common for software to choose a single category (race, in this case) as a baseline, and then give you coefficients for the remaining categories that represent how much they differ from the baseline category. The value of the baseline category is captured by the intercept term.

It is possible to force programs to exclude intercept terms, in which case they can instead provide coefficients for all the categories.

As user158565 notes in the comments, what you are asking for (an intercept plus coefficients for all races) does not make any sense. All the information in the model is captured with one less parameter than you are asking for!

We cannot provide you any further advice without knowing more about the model. Many users here (including me) do not use SPSS, so we don't know what you mean by Box 0 and Box 1.